# How long does it take to fill up the tank?

Tags: puzzle

It's a really simple question yet I cannot come up with the answer for it,

we have a tank of water, and we have $4$ people if they try to fill the tank separately it will take

- $1$st person $60$ minutes to fill
- $2$nd person $45$ minutes to fill
- $3$rd person $30$ minutes to fill
- $4$th person $15$ minutes to fill

how long does it take to fill the tank if they simultaneously try to fill the tank?

I've already tried to divide the first 3 persons time by the 4th persons time and get the final time

so if the 1st person and the 4th person try to fill the tank up

$15 / 4$(since it takes the first person 4 times as the last one). we get $3.75$ and subtract the total time it will be $11.25$

$15 / 3 = 5$ final time would be $11.25 - 5 = 6.25$

$15 / 2 = 7.5$ final time would be $6.25 - 7.5 = -1.25$

doing this will give me a negative result which is why I think my approach in incorrect

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.

Comment: @jjagmath thanks i've made an edit and specified what i've tried to do already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: the first person fills $\tfrac{1}{60}$ per minute, the second fills $\tfrac{1}{45}$ per minute, together they will fill $\tfrac{1}{60}+\tfrac{1}{45}$ per minute.

Comment: so $1/60 + 1/45 + 1/30 + 1/15 = 0.138888889$?

Comment: The sum in your comment is correct, but you still need to understand what that number means to get to the answer.

Comment: I can't really figure it out 

Comment: @Sarkar What unit do those numbers have? What unit should your final answer have?

Comment: it takes 0.1388 per minute so it should get filled up in $7.2$ minutes

Comment: Yes, that's the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @jjagmath and @Arthur

the first person fills up $1/60$ per minute

the second person fills up $1/45$ per minute

the third person fills up $1/30$ per minute

the fourth person fills up $1/15$ per minute

sum of all the fractions will be $0.138888889$

that's mean they fill $0.138888889$ per minute and in order to the tank to get filled it would take $1/0.138888889 = 7.2$ minutes

Comment: If you find my hint useful you could accept my answer.

Comment: We usually work with minutes and decimal seconds, rarely in decimal minutes. So better use rational calculation $\frac{36}{5}=7+\frac 15$ and convert the $\frac 15$ to $12$ seconds.